# How Can I Directly Connect ESP32 BLE with Mobile Bluetooth using Micropython?

Tags: python, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, micropython

I'm trying to Connect directly esp32 BLE with mobile without the help of the Bluetooth serial Terminal app. I used Thonny IDE for coding. When I tried to connect directly with mobile here is the pop-up I got.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fISYr.jpg

here is the code i used

```html
from machine import Pin, Timer, SoftI2C
from time import sleep_ms
import ubluetooth
from esp32 import raw_temperature
from hdc1080 import HDC1080

class BLE():
    def __init__(self, name):   
        self.name = name
        self.ble = ubluetooth.BLE()
        self.ble.active(True)

        self.led = Pin(2, Pin.OUT)
        self.timer1 = Timer(0)
        self.timer2 = Timer(1)
        
        self.disconnected()
        self.ble.irq(self.ble_irq)
        self.register()
        self.advertiser()

    def connected(self):        
        self.timer1.deinit()
        self.timer2.deinit()

    def disconnected(self):        
        self.timer1.init(period=1000, mode=Timer.PERIODIC, callback=lambda t: self.led(1))
        sleep_ms(200)
        self.timer2.init(period=1000, mode=Timer.PERIODIC, callback=lambda t: self.led(0))   

    def ble_irq(self, event, data):
        if event == 1:
            '''Central disconnected'''
            self.connected()
            self.led(1)
        
        elif event == 2:
            '''Central disconnected'''
            self.advertiser()
            self.disconnected()
        
        elif event == 3:
            '''New message received'''            
            buffer = self.ble.gatts_read(self.rx)
            message = buffer.decode('UTF-8').strip()
            print(message)            
            if message == 'red_led':
                red_led.value(not red_led.value())
                print('red_led', red_led.value())
                ble.send('red_led' + str(red_led.value()))
            if message == 'read_temp':
                print(sensor.read_temperature(True))
                ble.send(str(sensor.read_temperature(True)))
            if message == 'read_hum':
                print(sensor.read_humidity())
                ble.send(str(sensor.read_humidity()))
           
    def register(self):        
        # Nordic UART Service (NUS)
        NUS_UUID = '6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E'
        RX_UUID = '6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E'
        TX_UUID = '6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E'
            
        BLE_NUS = ubluetooth.UUID(NUS_UUID)
        BLE_RX = (ubluetooth.UUID(RX_UUID), ubluetooth.FLAG_WRITE)
        BLE_TX = (ubluetooth.UUID(TX_UUID), ubluetooth.FLAG_NOTIFY)
            
        BLE_UART = (BLE_NUS, (BLE_TX, BLE_RX,))
        SERVICES = (BLE_UART, )
        ((self.tx, self.rx,), ) = self.ble.gatts_register_services(SERVICES)

    def send(self, data):
        self.ble.gatts_notify(0, self.tx, data + '\n')

    def advertiser(self):
        name = bytes(self.name, 'UTF-8')
        self.ble.gap_advertise(100, bytearray('\x02\x01\x02') + bytearray((len(name) + 1, 0x09)) + name)
        
# test
i2c = SoftI2C(scl=Pin(22), sda=Pin(21))
sensor = HDC1080(i2c)
red_led = Pin(2, Pin.OUT)
ble = BLE("ESP32")
```

I can connect using the Bluetooth Serial Terminal app But My question is How can I connect directly without using Bluetooth serial terminal app

Comment: As your ESP32 device is BLE serial device, then you have no other option but to have application, that knows how to handle Serial communication.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I saw this piece of code somewhere on the internet as well.
Unfortunately this is an outdated code and it won't work with the current version of ubluetooth.
This is a quick list of ubluetooth.BLE from MicroPython firmware "esp32-20220618-v1.19.1.bin"

```
>>> import ubluetooth

>>> dir(ubluetooth.BLE)

['__class__', '__name__', '__bases__', '__dict__', 'active', 'config', 'gap_advertise', 'gap_connect', 'gap_disconnect', 'gap_scan', 'gattc_discover_characteristics', 'gattc_discover_descriptors', 'gattc_discover_services', 'gattc_exchange_mtu', 'gattc_read', 'gattc_write', 'gatts_indicate', 'gatts_notify', 'gatts_read', 'gatts_register_services', 'gatts_set_buffer', 'gatts_write', 'irq']
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33485832)